# Combinning Multiple Neural Networks

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function, blending

can you combine multiple neural networks and have a totally new loss function for the combined network.

I would like to assign a neural network for each part of the data (each part of an image for example) and optimize the solution with a totally new loss function.